# The meaning of "turnover" in "apple turnover"

Tags: meaning-in-context

why is it called "turnover" in "apple turnover"? I was only able find who made the first apple turnover (so it seems) in this [link](https://milkandhoneythebakery.com/apple-turnover-pastry-saves-village/#:%7E:text=Calais%2C%20in%20the%20Sarthe%20region,now%20know%20as%20apple%20turnovers.). Or maybe there is no reason why it's called that way. Thank you!

"Legend has it that in 1630 in St. Calais, in the Sarthe region of France, an epidemic had spread. The lady of the town, or the Chatelaine, in an effort to relieve their suffering, supplied the afflicted people with flour and apples. The resulting pastry was what we now know as apple turnovers."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make a turnover, you take a flat sheet of pastry, place chopped fruit, meat, vegetables (or a mixture) on half of it, then **turn over** (or fold over) the other half to make a lid or cover. Then you bake it in an oven.

It is easy to make, and does not require a great amount of skill.

[image]